# Bound for $e^{-\alpha x}$

Tags: exponential-function, functional-inequalities

For a part of my proof I need to establish that $e^{-\alpha x} \lt h(x)$, where $\alpha,x \gt 0, $ and $x,\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$. I thought for a while and couldn't find a function independent of $\alpha$ that fulfills my criteria. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking for an example of a function $h$ for which the inequality is true?

Comment: $h(x)=1$ fits the bill.

Comment: If you don't want any specific $h$, there are a lot (and basically useless) functions that bound $e^{-ax}$ from above. For example given any strictly positive integer $n$, $h_n(x)=n$ is always strictly larger than $e^{-ax}$ and independent of $a$.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question for lack of context. Without context, we cannot know what kinda of upper bound you want, and the question becomes too open-ended.

Comment: I do not want a specific h, just a h for which $h(x)\gt e^{-\alpha x}$ holds. I do not see how 1 fits the bill...

Comment: $$ \alpha,x>0\implies e^{-\alpha x}<1.$$

Comment: Ok, and what in the case that $h(x)$ must depend on $x$?

Comment: In that case take $h(x) = 1+x$

Comment: Alright thanks to all! Sometimes the solution is truly too easy...

Answer (score -1):

Also note that:
$$e^{-\alpha x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\alpha^nx^n}{n!}$$
A polynomial of this expansion could be used, although take care to see that it is consistently greater as this is a series with alternating sign

Comment: But a polynomial (of positive degree) gives a _worse_  bound than the obvious $h(x)=1$.

Comment: The higher order used the closer this approximation is surely, especially at smaller values of $x$, since $h(x)=1$ is most accurate for $x\to\infty$